# Stylus compiling doing wrong

Tags: css, stylus

everybody, hope you will help me out. I've start styling in styles and everything was with few block of website. But when I start to write div's for gallery (here's code of it)

```
body
    clearfix()
    text-align center
    background url('./bgh1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed
    background-size(cover)

#gallery
    margin-left 6%
    width 88%
    display block
    margin-left auto
    margin-right auto
    height 500px
    background black

    #line1
        width 980px
        height 345px
        background #ffffff

        #col1
            width 500px
            height 500px
            border 2px solid black
            img
                max-width 100%
                max-height 100%
```

It compiled with lot of mistakes

```
#gallery {
  margin-left: 6%;
  width: 88%;
}
#gallery display block {
  margin-left: auto;
}
#gallery margin-right auto {
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
}
#gallery margin-right auto #line1 width 980px {
  height: 345px;
  background: #fff;
}
#gallery margin-right auto #line1 #col1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
#gallery margin-right auto #line1 #col1 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

This command I've been using for compiling

```
stylus -w views/stylesheets/styl.styl -o views/style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Selectors: Indentation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html):

> Whitespace is significant [...]

You are mixing whitespaces and tabs (even on the same lines). Even if this looks OK in your editor, this might cause problems when whitespace *is* significant. So you should configure your editor to replace tabs with single whitespaces to avoid that problem.